# PHP: mysqli insert data is very slow

Tags: php, mysqli, indexing

I use below class for insert data:

```
class DB {
  protected static $connection;
    public $num = 0;
    public $insertID = 0;
    public $data = "";
    public $select = "";
    public $error = "";

  public function connect() {
    if(!isset(self::$connection)) {
      self::$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
      mysqli_query(self::$connection, "SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    }

    if(self::$connection === false) {
      echo 'Not Connect To Database !<br>'.self::$connection->connect_error;
      return false;
    }

    return self::$connection;
  }

  public function query($query) {
    $this->select = $query;
    $q = $this->connect()->query($query);
    $this->connect()->commit();

    return $q;
  }

public function insert($table, $params){
    $before = $after = '';

    foreach($params as $field => $value){
        $before .= "`$field`,";
        $after .= "'$value',";
    }

    $before = substr($before,0,-1);
    $after = substr($after,0,-1);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$table` ($before) VALUES ($after)";
    if($this->query($sql)){
        $this->insertID = mysqli_insert_id($this->connect());
    }

    return true;
  }
}
```

And this is my table :

[image]

And this is my code :

```
$array = array( 'basketPrice'=>$detail['price'],
                    'basketOrder'=>$orderId,
                    'basketGift'=>$userGift,
                    'basketUseCredit'=>$cr,
                    'basketProduct'=>$product,
                    'basketFinish'=>$detail['buyPrice'],
                    'basketExSoon'=>$detail['minus']);

$db = new DB();
$db->insert('basket', $array);
```

In my database save about 80.000 records. after run code, i get timeout and insert into table not work

basketId, basetGift and basketOrder are indexes
Why ?

Answer (score -1):

Try to insert the records in bunches. This will not cause timeout. Try splitting your records to like 100 inserts per call. Since you have indexes associated with the columns so it is evident that why the insertion are taking time. Having large number of indexe affects the performance of insertion in DB. So choose the indexes wisely.